# Light weight, behavior driven multi-agent robot simulator?

Tags: development-environment, simulation, environment, robotics

Looking for a robot simulator that's multi-agent, light weight, behavior driven, and scriptible, visual runtime -- it's likely 2D too. There is no requirement for the logic to be output to the real world. Aside from behaviors related to sensor/motor combos - it'd be nice if it was possible to code sensor to respond to color/size/speed/etc (prey/predator/mating) and have events that happen as a result contact (death/birth/energy-gain).

So, far I've looked at the following, none of which have semi-complex behavior assignment, rendering and reporting:

**BugWorks:** multi-agent, behavior driven, light weight, visual runtime -- but not scriptible as far as I'm able to tell; meaning you can use a GUI, and save it, but their no code output to edit directly. One thing that is nice is there's a reproduce function; although the implementation is odd, it produces one robot per click (it's not based on robot interaction) and appears to take an average of all the attributes of all robots presents; better than no function though. [More info](http://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/users/christ/bugworks/)

**Guido van Robot:** not multi-agent, but it's got it's own simple scripting language for the robot and environment, with a debugger built in. [More Info](http://gvr.sourceforge.net/)

**Algodoo:** It's got  2D Physics, point-n-click interface, but very heavy on the graphic card, so I have tested it out much. [More info](http://www.algodoo.com)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can use the ARIA C++ libraries (both Java and Python wrappers available) in conjunction with the MobileSim simulator:

http://robots.mobilerobots.com/wiki/ARIA
http://robots.mobilerobots.com/wiki/MobileSim

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can give [GarlicSim](http://garlicsim.org) a try. It's a generic simulations framework (good for multi-agent simulation among others,) so it might not provide the specific tools you need for robot simulation, but it will make it relatively easy for you to build them.

Comment: +1, but looked at GarlicSim for 5-mins, and was unable to find any "simpacks" -- meaning all GarlicSim is based on my understanding is a "simpacks" player. What the point of a player if there's nothing to play on it?

Comment: There are three simpacks that ship with GarlicSim. They are in the `garlicsim_lib` module. (Google it.) But they are just example simpacks; For your simulation you'll have to write your own simpack. Keep in mind that the goal of GarlicSim is to make it as easy as possible to write simpacks. Eventually there will be a rich standard library of simpacks in `garlicsim_lib`, but that's years from now.

Comment: Guess it would have been good too if in your answer you'd disclosed your affiliation with GarlicSim; which I just found by looking at your profile. At any rate, I agree that it should help, and is a good project -- just know the the simpacks, not the player will lead to the success of the project IMHO.